# Find The Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

There will be 3 vectors in $R^3$ $V_1= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix} $ , $V_2= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} $, $V_3= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 4\\ 7\\ \end{pmatrix}$

and 3 vectors in $R^2$ $W_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} $ $W_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} $  $W_3=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\-2\\ \end{pmatrix} $

find $T$ for $T(V_i)=(W_i)$

I know T needs to be a $R^{2x3}$ but if I use the elementary basis of $R^3$ I get a $R^{3x3}$

Comment: The columns in a matrix are the images of the vectors $(1,0,\ldots),(0,1,0,\ldots),\ldots$. Using that, can you write down a matrix which maps $(1,0,0)$ to $W_1$, $(0,1,0)$ to $W_2$ and $(0,0,1)$ to $W_3$?

Comment: If you've done that, you should also be able to write down a (3x3) matrix which maps $(1,0,0)$ to $V_1$, $(0,1,0)$ to $V_2$ and $(0,0,1)$ to $V_3$.

Comment: Now, to map $V_1$ to $W_1$, how do you have to combine the two matrices?

Comment: Note that $3V_1-2V_2=V_3$. Applying $T$, $3W_1-2W_2=W_3$. But that's false, so there's no such $T$.

Comment: Sorry all I had a mistake with the $W_3$

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are any two finite dimensional vector spaces and $b_i$ is a basis of $V$ and $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation then the columns of $T$ are $Tb_1, Tb_2, \dots$ etc. This is because in the basis $b_i$ the vectors $b_i$ have the coordinates $(1,0,0 \dots), (0,1,0,\dots),$ etc.

Of course, the entries of the matrix of $T$ when you write it down on paper depend on whatever basis (of $W$) the $Tb_i$ are given in.

Now for the problem at hand: Note that $V_i$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Also note that you are given $TV_i$ with respect to the standard basis $(1 0), (0 1)$ of $\mathbb R^2$. As a consequence, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $V_i$ and the standard basis $e_1,e_2$ equals $\widetilde{T}=(W_1W_2W_3)$ (the matrix with columns $W_i$).

To obtain the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^2$ all that remains to be done is this: find the matrix $B$ that maps a vector $v$ given with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ to $v$ given with respect to $V_i$ and compute $\widetilde{T} \cdot B$.

But $B$ is simply the matrix $(V_1V_2V_3)$.